# Does it matter if you check whether a file or image exists using the domain in the path way to check the file in PHP?

Tags: php, php-5.3

Is using the root path of a website and the domain name of a website the same when creating thumbnails with php ..I mean , they point to the same location right ?

for example

`define('ROOT',$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']);` which outputs `'var/www/html'` path
and I have my other constant

```
define('SITE_WS_PATH','http://www.example.com/uploads');
```

When checking an image file in PHP or other file operations , can I also use the normal root path using the domain from the constant SITE_WS_PATH or does it matter at all ?  is using the $DOCUMENT_ROOT version a requirement ... I use the domain constant SITE_WS_PATH , but I am wondering if it matters ..

For example , is it good to do this

```
is_file(SITE_WS_PATH.'/'.$image_name) {

// do something

}
```

Or should it be

```
is_file(ROOT.'/'.$image_name) {

// do something

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `ROOT` check accesses the local file system, so it can tell whether any file exists on the server. Using `SITE_WS_PATH` method goes thrugh the webserver, so it can only detect files that can be accessed from the Internet. If you have rewrite rules or restrictions in `.htaccess`, this method will be affected by them. Also, going through the webserver will be slower and put more load on the webserver.

You also seem to be missing `uploads` in `ROOT`.

Comment: Off-top, question: Does your company (bridgebase) have about 300-400$ to make a decent a modern site design? (it looks like it was made in 1990 or so)

Comment: We have 4 programmers. And I spend too much of my time here on SO :)

Comment: 4 developers and no web-designers at all? Man, people want to see beautiful things in 2014, they don't want to think they found ancient site :) (I hope you agree on that)

Comment: @Barmar so basically I have to use the ROOT method , $_SERVER['document_root] .. right ?

Comment: That's what I recommend.